# Problems with jQuery bind()

Tags: jquery

I'm getting an `Unexpected TOKEN illegal` error on the following javascript:

```
$(function() {  
    $(‘.delete_post’).bind(‘ajax:success’, function() {  
        $(this).closest(‘tr’).fadeOut();  
    });  
});
```

I've done quite a bit of research and can't seem to find any issue with this code. The error is being thrown on the 2nd line. The `.delete_post` refers to a Destroy link class that should be removing elements from a page.

Any thoughts?

EDIT:
The actual error given in the Chrome console is:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Comment: Whats with the funny single quotes?  Perhaps this is your problem?

Comment: Thanks @John, I think that is just a formatting thing on SO, that's just my normal single quote. Should I be using something differently?

Comment: @cmwright: What are you using to edit your code?

Comment: @icktoofay i'm editing in TextMate, why?

Comment: @cmwright: That's very, very, odd, because those quotes got in there somehow, and I know both TextMate and Stack Overflow will not change quotes. Did you copy something from a WordPress blog? WordPress changes quotes automatically sometimes.

Comment: @icktoofay thanks for your help, that's exactly what happened. i'll know to look out for next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using back-tics instead of single quotes (apostrophes).

-- Per comments --

They're not backticks, they're left single quotes (thanks Gabi).  Unfortunately, That's still probably enough to throw off the JS Engine.  If you didn't mean to type them that way your editor is doing it automagically.  What platform / editor are you working with?

Comment: Those are not backticks. They are actually `U+2018 LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK`

Comment: @Gabi - They're not apostrophes either, which is what's probably throwing the illegal TOKEN error.

Comment: Hey guys, as i mentioned above, that's just how SO is displaying my ' when inside of backticks for code. Should I be using something else?

Comment: @cmwright: Stack Overflow doesn't change quotes, at least that I've ever seen.

Comment: @cmwright - SO is really good about not modifying code that you paste.  If that's what you've pasted then whatever editor you are using is changing your apostrophes for you.  You need a better editor / IDE.

Comment: thanks guys, you were right. I was having another problem so i copy-pasted from another source. Somehow the formatting coming from html came across into textmate. The quick response is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
 delete('quotes')
```

Is looking a bit different in my preview